# Is there a python function for creating a nested JSON file from a DF?

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I'm trying to built a dataframe starting from the schema that the final JSON file should have.

The schema is the following:

```
[{"plant": ,
  "at": ,
  "products": [{
          "product": ,
          "quantity": ,
      }]
```

Plant should be a string, at should be a date ISO8601, product should be a string, quantity should be an integer.

I built the dataframe as follows:

```
Plant    At         Products    Product    Quantity
XXX    2019-06-07   products    product1     4
YYY    2019-06-07   products    product2     -9
ZZZ    2019-06-07   products    product3     2099
```

And now I'm trying to generate the nested JSON file, but the code I'm using does not work as desired

```
j2 = (df2.groupby(['plant', 'at'], as_index=False)
    .apply(lambda x: x[['product', 'quantity']].to_dict('r'))
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: 'products'})
    .to_json(orient='columns'))
```

I get this JSON

```
{"plant":{"0":"XXX","1":"YYY","2":"ZZZ"},"at":{"0":"2019-06-07 12:53:13.983775","1":"2019-06-07 12:53:13.983775","2":"2019-06-07 12:53:13.983775"},"products":{"0":[{"product":product1,"quantity":4}],"1":[{"product":product2,"quantity":-9}],"2":[{"product":product3,"quantity":2099}]}}
```

But actually it isn't the format I should generate.

Any suggestion? Is there a way to mantain the ISO8601 formatting for the dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use orient = 'records'

```
df2.groupby(['Plant', 'At'])['Product', 'Quantity'].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).reset_index(name = 'Products').to_json(orient = 'records')
```

You get

```
[{"Plant":"XXX",
"At":"2019-05-03",
"Products":[{"Product":"Product1","Quantity":4}]}]
```